# Get module version in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I have a module installed on my Prestashop and I want to get its version

How can I do this in my code ?

[image]

Let's say for example I want to get "v5.0.1"

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$module = Module::getInstanceByName('bienvenue');
$version = $module->version;
```

Comment: Thank you ! Another question if you can help : I want to use this in a custom module. So, I extend the Module class : "MyModule extends Module". I have another class in my project where I need to get the version of MyModule. So I just have to do this : MyModule::getInstanceByName("MyModule") ?

Comment: You're welcome. in your module (mymodule.php), for checking self version use: "echo $this->version;" and in other module (etcmodule.php) or anywhere else use above way: "$module = Module::getInstanceByName('mymodule');echo $module->version; "

Comment: I [just learned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54470465/875020) that you dont need to hardcode the modules name but can instead access it via `$this->module->name` and also dont need to call `Module::getInstanceByName()` but instead access `$this->module`.

Answer (score 1):

The version is set in the module file like that:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->name = 'bienvenue';
    $this->version = '5.0.1';

    parent::__construct();

    /* Else code... */
}
```