# Get name of module in PrestaShop front controller

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

In PrestaShop (specifically v1.7.5) one [can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28600358/875020) get an [instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52274207/875020) of the module class by calling

```
$module = Module::getInstanceByName('theModuleName');
```

in the controller of a custom module.

Is `'theModuleName'` available via some other setting or variable or does it need to be hardcoded?

It should also be used as first parameter to [`getModuleLink()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25085520/875020).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the module name (along with the rest from the module class) by:

```
$theModuleName = $this->module->name;
```

Using Prestashop core module "Cronjobs" as an example, you can also run module methods inside a front controller like this:

```
class CronjobsCallbackModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
    public function postProcess()
    {
        $this->module->sendCallback();
        die;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks, i guess my workaround to assign `$this->module='mymodulename';` in the constructor of the controller only made things worse ;) - Also, this makes the call to `Module::getInstanceByName()` unnecessary!

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in a child from ProductListingFrontController, this->module is not defined.
If you call the module with getInstanceByName, you get an instance in order to work with it later. The string way doesn´t work in Listing controllers.

```
class mymoduleMyControllerModuleFrontController extends ProductListingFrontControllerCore
     {
        public function init()
        {
            parent::init();
    
            $this -> module = Module::getInstanceByName('mymodule');
    }
}
```