# How to call a module static function from another module in PrestaShop 1.7+

Tags: module, prestashop

I'm trying to call static function of module named: `Mymodule` from another module like this: `Mymodule::doThis()`

But got error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Mymodule' not found

I know, I can use code:
`include_once _PS_MODULE_DIR_.'mymodule/mymodule.php'`,
but I want to know if I can use class autoloading or other elegant way to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
Mymodule::getInstanceByName('doThis');
```

more explanation here :

[Get name of module in PrestaShop front controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54469035/get-name-of-module-in-prestashop-front-controller/54470465#54470465)

Comment: As I said trying to use Mymodule class causes error: Class 'Mymodule' not found. I suppose you wanted me to use Module::getInstanceByName('Mymodule'); instead ?

Comment: Yes try this way to call your method

Comment: Add a namespace for your module class, or you have to include the php file where MyModule class is defined https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php